# How can I put an existing activity into PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity activity1 and I want to use it inside PreferenceFragment ,as a result the PreferenceFragment will display my activity How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can put an intent in your preference that will open your Activity:

[from the official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html):

For example, here's how you can use a preference item to open a web page:

```
<Preference android:title="@string/prefs_web_page" >
   <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
           android:data="http://www.example.com" />
```

You can create both implicit and explicit intents using the following attributes:

```
android:action
```

The action to assign, as per the setAction() method.

```
android:data
```

The data to assign, as per the setData() method.

```
android:mimeType
```

The MIME type to assign, as per the setType() method.

```
android:targetClass
```

The class part of the component name, as per the setComponent() method.
    android:targetPackage
The package part of the component name, as per the setComponent() method.

You would put your class name into

```
android:targetClass
```

and your package name into:

```
android:targetPackage
```

Please try and let me know how it goes

Comment: I didn't know what did you mean ?